# Adding new folders to pub directory and accessing?

Tags: magento2

I have added a folder in the pub directory
installdir/myfolder

I placed a pdf in the folder
installdir/myfolder/myfile.pdf

When I try accessing the file via a link Magento states that the file cannot be found or that it is "Not Allowed"

What is the correct method of accessing this file?

Comment: probably the wrong file permissions and ownership. pdf must be readable by the web server user

Comment: Yes, I figured so. Can I solve it all with chmod and the right permissions?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct method of accessing this file?

You can try to give full permissions.

```
chmod -Rf 777 /var/www/magento207/myfolder/
```

I have tried it and i able to access PDF.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to give everything all permissions. Would it work by running 777 on just pub/media?

Comment: Give the permission  (readable) to your folder only "myfolder" which contains PDF.

Comment: 404 error: Page not found. / This path is not allowed.

Comment: Set 777 permission to specific PDF file folder, you can access.